# Plotting correlation coefficient values against time?

Tags: matlab, correlation

my correlation coefficient values are:

```
corr=[0.54   0.81   0.21   0.61   0.52   0.47   -0.42   -0.20].
```

The corresponding time for these correlation coefficient values are:

```
T=[00:00 -  00:27:02    00:27:02 - 00:35:02    00:35:02 - 00:47:02     00:47 - 00:59:55   01:05:02 - 01:12    01:15 - 01:25    01:27 - 01:35  01:35 - 01:45  ].
```

The time is given in hour: minute: second format.I want to plot the correlation coefficient values against time. Also, I want to get a 95% confidence line. The example is given in the link https://www.researchgate.net/post/plotting_correlation_coefficient_values_against_time. any help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I'm splitting the date strings into start & end times and then I'm converting them to numbers:

```
coeffs = [0.54 0.81 0.21 0.61 0.52 0.47 -0.42 -0.20];
T = {'00:00 - 00:27:02', '00:27:02 - 00:35:02', '00:35:02 - 00:47:02', '00:47 - 00:59:55', '01:05:02 - 01:12', '01:15 - 01:25', '01:27 - 01:35', '01:35 - 01:45'};
% split to start and end times
startEndTimes = cellfun(@(str) strsplit(str,' - '),T,'UniformOutput',0);
startTimes = cellfun(@(c) c{1},startEndTimes,'UniformOutput',0);
endTimes = cellfun(@(c) c{2},startEndTimes,'UniformOutput',0);
% add seconds where missing
missingSecondsIdx = cellfun(@length,startTimes) == 5;
startTimes(missingSecondsIdx) = cellfun(@(str) [str ':00'],startTimes(missingSecondsIdx),'UniformOutput',0);
missingSecondsIdx = cellfun(@length,endTimes) == 5;
endTimes(missingSecondsIdx) = cellfun(@(str) [str ':00'],endTimes(missingSecondsIdx),'UniformOutput',0);
% convert time strings to numbers
startTimeNums = datenum(startTimes,'HH:MM:SS');
EPS = 1e-4;
endTimeNums = datenum(endTimes,'HH:MM:SS') - EPS;
% interpolate coefficients on "continous" time vector
contTime = linspace(startTimeNums(1),endTimeNums(end),200);
repCoeffs = repmat(coeffs,[2 1]);
repCoeffs = repCoeffs(:);
allTimes = [startTimeNums';endTimeNums'];
allTimes = allTimes(:);
contCoeffs = interp1(allTimes,repCoeffs,contTime);
% plot
plot(contTime,contCoeffs,'b')
hold on;
plot(startTimeNums,coeffs,'og')
plot(endTimeNums,coeffs,'*r')
datetick('x','HH:MM')
xlabel('TIME [HH:MM]')
ylabel('CORRELATION COEFFICIENTS')
```

[image]

Comment: sir, I think, I need to explain my question. In my question, I have calculated the correlation coefficients according to time as, my correlation coefficient value at the time (00:00:00 -  00:27:02 is 0.54), at the time (00:27:02 - 00:35:02 is 0.81 ) and so on. I don't know that why you have split the time into and end time. Also if possible then please give a short code for this. thanks for your response. I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: I want to get a plot showing the correlation coefficient value for each time event. I think you can answer this question.waiting for your reply. thanks

Comment: your coefficients are calculated for time **intervals** (rather then time points), so I plotted it for time intervals as well.

Comment: sir, the figure is given in the link also shows that the correlation coefficient is calculated for the event but your plot is looking different from the one in the link. for the explanation, you can see the discussion about figure.4 of the paper in the link below. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/29624675_Are_variations_in_PMSE_intensity_affected_by_energetic_particle_precipitation. thanks

Comment: @ user2999345, sir, if you know the answer to my question then kindly reply to my comments. Also, i don't know the use of (EPS = 1e-4) and also, i don't know that for (contTime = linspace(startTimeNums(1),endTimeNums(end),200), why you have used 200.

Comment: I used `EPS` to separate the start & end times. `200` is just an arbitrary "large enough" number of samples to simulate continuous time.

Comment: is there any rule to select this arbitrary number like the one you have selected as 200. I want to study this in detail, so if you have any link related to this concern then kindly share with me.

Comment: @ user2999345, sir, why this needed here to replicate the (coeffs) as         repmat(coeffs,[2 1]).

Comment: because each coefficient has two time points - start & end. and no rule for the arbitrary number, it's just for smoothness.

Comment: @ user2999345, thanks for your informative discussion.

Comment: ,sir, if use the 'coeffs' Time interval values in your code then it gives me error. if possible then kindly help me.                    
coeffs =  [0.40  -0.41  -0.09  -0.45  -0.03  0.18  -0.42  0.19  0.25  0.66 0.45  0.66];
T = {'00:30- 00:59:55',  '01:00- 01:27:02',  '01:43:02-01:59:55',  '02:00-02:11:02',  '02:25:02- 02:40',  '02:40– 02:59:55',  '03:00- 03:37:02', '06:13:02-  06:32', '20:50- 20:59:55', '21:40– 21:50', '21:48– 21:59:55', '21:40– 21:59:55'}.

Comment: @ user2999345,  sir is this possible to get a plot of correlation coefficients for a different interval having no connection between the plot lines of the correlation coefficient of different time intervals. an example is given in the edited link of the question. thanks